# WordPress Unit Testing with is_plugin_active()

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing

The plugin I'm unit testing with phpunit has a dependency on another plugin, using `is_plugin_active()`.

When testing the dependency in my unit test that function always returns false/inactive, when the it is definitely active, because it's working properly in the plugin itself. It seems to be accessible, so there must be some logic error when it comes to this wordpress core function.

This is my code:

```
function test_requirementsMet_true() {
$this->assertTrue(is_plugin_active('pluginFolder/plugin.php'));
}
```

Does anyone know of a work-around?

Comment: That function is usually only available from the admin area of WordPress. Have you loaded `/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`?

Comment: @rnevius I added `include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');` before the assert statement and it still functions the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you scaffolded your tests with WP-CLI, you should know the plugin is loaded as an mu-plugin rather than a vanilla plugin, [which means](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/):

> Only plugins installed in the plugins/ folder can be active.
>
> Plugins in the mu-plugins/ folder can’t be "activated," so this
>   function will return false for those plugins.